# How to clear the md-autocomplete cache?

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, angular-material

I'm using `md-autocomplete` to show results of an api query.  Attribute `md-items` is iterating over a promise: `item in getItems(searchText)`.

This is working well, and using the cache subsequent uses of the same search text return immediately with the same results.

But I need to be able to clear the cache at some points, when other search parameters change.  How can I do this?  By accessing the md-autocomplete controller perhaps?  Although that seems non-standard and I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As of version 1.0.5 of angular-material this isn't possible.  I didn't find any acceptable workarounds, so I'm just disabling the cache with `md-no-cache="true"`.

I've [logged an issue for this](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/7411) on the angular-material project including a suggestion on how it could work.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. I'm loading different lists to the md-autocomplete component depending on an user input and the old values was stored together with the new one. Turning off the cache released all the old values.

Comment: Any news on this now?

Comment: The issue I filed was closed as it's not considered core enough. Disappointing, but I've been able to work around it by keeping md-no-cache="true" and adding our own caching layer. The md-items expression can take a function like: md-items="item in getItems(searchText)".

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely possible to reset the `md-no-cache` attribute programmatically anytime on your `md-autocomplete` directive.

If you have a boolean variable on your controller, let's say:

```
$scope.noCacheResults = false;
```

Then on your directive you can bind this variable to the `md-no-cache` attribute:

```
<md-autocomplete ...
                 md-no-cache="noCacheResults">
</md-autocomplete>
```

Like this, whenever your search parameters change you can set the `$scope.noCacheResults` to `true` or `false` depending whether you want to keep caching the query results or not.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. It may work when you go from false to true but true to false, it will keep old results in cache. As a workaround, I disabled the cache `md-no-cache="true"`

Answer (score -1):

Something that worked for me.  Put an ng-if on your autocomplete.  Then, in the code that changes the value of the other fields affecting this field, set that value to false, and then within a timeout, set it to true again.  This will effectively remove the item from the DOM and put it back all nice and new with no cache.

Comment: This is such a bad solution! C'mon?